# Accessing Static Library wrapped in XCFramework

Tags: ios, xcode, sdk, static-libraries, xcframework

We have Static library (*.a) wrapped in XCFramework distributed by a third-party SDK. Attached is screenshot of the SDK's directory structure and info.plist.

Our project structure -> Main App - SubProject - SDK

Existing integration was with static library. We had SDK's header file imported in sub-project's headers.

What is not working?

- Importing XCFramework gives `No such module $FRAMEWORK`
- Accessing SDK content gives `Cannot find $FRAMEWORK in scope`
  -- Expected as import is not working.

What I have tried so far?

- Linker flags `-ObjC -all_load`
- Setting Library & header search paths
  -- Path for header file is bit tricky with directory names `ios-arm64_armv7_armv7s` & `ios-arm64_i386_x86_64-simulator`
- Creating SPM repo for the framework.

Only way I can get this working is copying `.h` file from XCFramework to the project and updating sub-project's header file.

That seems wrong though. Any ideas what I am missing?

[image: XCFramework directory structure]

[image: Info.plist]

Comment: have you found any way to use this? please share it

Answer (score 0):

Possibly you need a `Bridging-Header.h` then import your iOS header as:

```
#import "iOS/ADBMobile.h"
```